# How to sum rows of submatrices in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization

## Summary

I have a working that solves my problem as described below, but would like to improve on it by eliminating the loop.

## Description

I have a matrix `B` in Matlab of dimension `(2*5)x3`which is a concatenation of `2` matrices of `5` rows and where the `ik`th element reports an index from `{1,2,3,4,5}`(breaks added for clarity) . The indices can be repeated across rows. For each submatrix of dimension `5x3` of `B` the listed indices and the order in which they are listed coincide.

```
B=[0.1 0.2 |1;
   0.3 0.4 |2;
   0.5 0.6 |2;
   0.7 0.8 |3;
   0.9 1.1 |1;
   ---------
   1.2 1.3 |1;
   1.4 1.5 |2;
   1.6 1.7 |2;
   1.8 1.9 |3;
   2.1 2.2 |1;]
```

Inside each submatrix of dimension `5x3` of `B` I would like to sum the rows with same index and get

```
C = [1   1.3 |1;
     0.8 1   |2;
     0.7 0.8 |3;
     ---------
     3.3 3.5 |1;
     3   3.2 |2;
     1.8 1.9 |3;]
```

without looping.

## What have I tried

My incomplete, but working, attempt with one loop:

```
D = permute(reshape(B,5,2,[]),[1 3 2]);
sum=zeros(3,2,2);
for i=1:2
    E=D(:,:,i);
    [b,c] = size(E);
    rows = ceil(1/(c-1):1/(c-1):b);
    cols = repmat(1:c-1,1,b);
    sum(:,:,i) = full(sparse(E(rows,end), cols, E(:,1:end-1).')); 
end
```

Comment: First of all, what have you tried? And secondly, why are you doing this? It feels like you may be taking a complicated detour to achieve something simple.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I know how to do it with a loop but in my actual code B is a very big matrix and I would like to avoid looping.

Comment: If you already have a working solution, make sure to include it in your question. It will help people to verify their solutions and deal with ambiguities. It also allows them to offer improvements instead of writing a solution from scratch. (For example, if you have multiple nested loops, vectorizing the inner one may already boost your performance to near optimal).

Comment: You can use "accumarray" to achieve this. ps using "sum" and "i" is not good since they are preserved function or variable.

Comment: Normally, if you have data in a matrix and want to treat different parts of the matrix separately: this means that you have done something wrong. I think that is why Dennis Jaheruddin asked what you were trying to achieve. Anyway, if you keep this matrix I am afraid it is impossible to solve the problem without loops. Matlab does only work with matrices. I does not know exactly what you want to do.